# Extra blank space between words

Tags: openrefine

Please help me with 2 questions on how to do the GREL expression for:

1. If there are double spaces between 2 words in a column, how can I eliminate 1 space Example: Robert--Smith to Robert-Smith The minus character equals a blank for illustration
2. How can I look for an exact word in a text filter.

Thanks!

Comment: To help to keep the discussion focus on a single topic, please post one question per post.

Answer (score 4):

1°) try transform---> value.replace("  "," ")

Or, simply common transforms ----> collapse consecutive white spaces

2°) Column ---> text filters and enter you word

Or, do column---> Facet---> Customs facet and type : value.contains(" you_word ")
or value.contains(/(yourexactword)/)
This will return a True or False facet

H.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

@hpiedcoq is the right answer if you need to have them in GREL. if not you can just use the point and click interface:

for the first question: Select your column and select Edit cells > Common transforms > Collapse consecutive white space

for the second question: select your column > text filter > enter the work you are looking for. You can select case sensitive if you want to take into account upper and lower case in your search.

Answer (score 0):

1.1 transform -- > `value.replace("  "," ")` 
Deletes all double whitespace.

1.2 transform -- > `value.trim()`
Deletes all double whitespace and deletes whitespaces before and after the string.

1.3 transform -- > `value.replace(/\b  \b/," ")`
   Replace with regular expression,  deletes only double whitespace between two words.

2. Text filter > turn on regular expression and use `\b`.
   Text filter with regular expression: `\bWord\b` = exact word, before and after the word may or may not be a only whitespace.